# Tool for filling a .Net Dataset with data

Tags: .net, dataset

Is there a tool for filling a System.Data.Dataset with test data?

Comment: Any data? Specific data? multiple tables? Related tables with FK/etc?

Comment: For my purposes a single table, the data values are not important, just random data for all data types defined by the columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Is the dataset in question already have a defined schema or are you just needing some/any test data?

If any data will do Northwind is a test db you can use for sample business data:

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that using a tool to generate the test data once and store it in a database from which you could repeatably fill the dataset would be a better solution.  There are several tools that you could use to do this: Red Gate [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm), EMS [Data Generator](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products), etc.

Comment: *Just* before hitting enter, I see "1 Response Posted..." - I should have known you'd beat me to it!

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what I am after. These tools seem to create the data in a database whereas I am looking to fill a typed dataset at runtime with data.

Comment: @JDKing -- I understand.  I'm suggesting that the way to do is to generate the data once and store it in a database, then simply load it each time you want to populate the dataset.  If you find bugs that aren't caught using the initial random data you can always add new data by hand to cover them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I see where you are coming from, but I'd rather not have the dependency on a database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) tool from Red Gate.  I recommend anything they build but I think this one does just what you're asking for.